# File-Roller: -p option at *.tar archives?

Tags: file-roller

Is the gui archive manager file-roller automatically using the "-p" option (preserve permissions) to create tar and tar.gz archives?

(It isn't mentioned in the GNOME documentation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, it does, according to this [bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=340050) and the sources since version 2.15.91:

```c
fr_command_tar_add (FrCommand  *comm,
            const char *from_file,
            GList      *file_list,
            const char *base_dir,
            gboolean    update,
            gboolean    follow_links)
{
    FrCommandTar *c_tar = FR_COMMAND_TAR (comm);
    GList        *scan;

    fr_process_set_out_line_func (FR_COMMAND (comm)->process,
                      process_line__add,
                      comm);

    begin_tar_command (comm);
    fr_process_add_arg (comm->process, "--force-local");
    fr_process_add_arg (comm->process, "--no-recursion");
    fr_process_add_arg (comm->process, "--no-wildcards");
    fr_process_add_arg (comm->process, "-v");
    fr_process_add_arg (comm->process, "-p");
```

The last line is the important one. Is also in the NEWS file:

```
version 2.15.91
----------------
    * Fixed bug #343739 – Seems to not escape file names correctly.
    * Fixes bug #340050 – tar permissions are not preserved.
```

The sources are from version 3.12.1, and the lines are still there.